# Using MichaCo\CacheManager with Redis

Tags: cachemanager

I'm looking to using [MichaCo\CacheManager](https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager) with Redis. Although the project page mentions that distributed cache with Redis is supported. But I do not see any examples of Redis configuration, setting up the environment etc. Anyone have experience with using this library with Redis in their project? Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many examples of how to use CacheManager in the code base and on http://cachemanager.michaco.net. The configuration example for Redis is even on the home page.

If you don't know how to set up a Redis server, just go to http://redis.io.
I'm using Redis for unit tests and local testing, too. It is all in the code base (see Tools folder) ;)

There is also a Windows version of Redis, if you don't want to run a linux instance, which can be installed via Nuget (package name is redis-64).

edit: almost forgot, there is also an article of how to create an application using [Redis with CacheManager](http://cachemanager.michaco.net/Documentation/Index/cachemanager_backed_todo_web_app)